# Django comments framework, set default form values

Tags: django, forms, comments

I defined a custom comment form in forms.py as fallow

```
class CommentFormWithReply(CommentForm):
    reply_to = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=CommentWithReply.objects.all(),
            widget=forms.HiddenInput(), required=False)

    def get_comment_model(self):
        # Use our custom comment model instead of the built-in one.
        return CommentWithReply

    def get_comment_create_data(self):
        # Use the data of the superclass, and add in the title field
        data = super(CommentFormWithReply, self).get_comment_create_data()
        return data
```

what should I do to render this form with the current user information as default values (name, email, webpage ).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

may be this:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#initial

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = CommentFormWithReply(request.POST)
    .........................................


if request.method == 'GET':
    default_data = {'name': 'Alexey', 'email': 'smt@email.smt', 'webpage': 'http://example.com'}
    form = CommentFormWithReply(default_data)
```

Comment: I need to do this the first time I render the form, and I want to use the data from the authenticated user

Comment: if request.method == 'GET':
    default_data = {'name': request.user.first_name, 'email': request.user.email, 'webpage': your.custom_field.from.userprofile}
    form = CommentFormWithReply(default_data)

Comment: or you can do it in CommentFormWithReply